# How to pause and resume a HTML5 animation?

Tags: javascript, html, smoothie.js

I am using "smoothie charts" http://smoothiecharts.org/.
I'm trying to make the animation stop and restart, but all I can do is freeze the "viewing" image. The animation doesn't really stop. It seems to continue to run in the background?

Once I restart it, the entire chart jumps to actual time.

On "start" I need that animation to resume, from where it was paused.
How can I achieve this?

I'm new with to this and have been trying to figure it out for a week, but i'm stuck on this problem.

This is the code for animation:

```
 SmoothieChart.AnimateCompatibility = (function() {
    var requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
          var requestAnimationFrame =
            window.requestAnimationFrame        ||
            window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame  ||
            window.mozRequestAnimationFrame     ||
            window.oRequestAnimationFrame       ||
            window.msRequestAnimationFrame      ||
            function(callback) {
              return window.setTimeout(function() {
                callback(new Date().getTime());
              }, 16);
            };
          return requestAnimationFrame.call(window, callback, element);
        },
        cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
          var cancelAnimationFrame =
            window.cancelAnimationFrame ||
            function(id) {
              clearTimeout(id);
            };
          return cancelAnimationFrame.call(window, id);
        };

    return {
      requestAnimationFrame: requestAnimationFrame,
      cancelAnimationFrame: cancelAnimationFrame
    };
  })();
```

And here is the original stop...

```
SmoothieChart.prototype.stop = function() {
if (this.frame) {
  SmoothieChart.AnimateCompatibility.cancelAnimationFrame(this.frame);
    delete this.frame;
  }
};
```

This is the start function

```
 SmoothieChart.prototype.start = function() {
    if (this.frame) {
      // We're already running, so just return
      return;
    }
    // Make sure the canvas has the optimal resolution for the device's pixel ratio.
    if (this.options.enableDpiScaling && window && window.devicePixelRatio !== 1) {
      var canvasWidth = this.canvas.getAttribute('width');
      var canvasHeight = this.canvas.getAttribute('height');

      this.canvas.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth * window.devicePixelRatio);
      this.canvas.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight * window.devicePixelRatio);
      this.canvas.style.width = canvasWidth + 'px';
      this.canvas.style.height = canvasHeight + 'px';
      this.canvas.getContext('2d').scale(window.devicePixelRatio, window.devicePixelRatio);
    }

    // Renders a frame, and queues the next frame for later rendering
    var animate = function() {
      this.frame = SmoothieChart.AnimateCompatibility.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        this.render();
        animate();
      }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this);

    animate();

  };
```

Comment: If you are using the [hello world example given](http://smoothiecharts.org/examples/example1.html), I would suspect that `setInterval` and the fact that the data is randomly created based on the current time to be the causes of your problems. It should not happen with an other set of data.

Comment: Hi @Kaiido, Well in my project we are using 5 diferent source of data  and this problems remains...  I apreciate if you have more tips.